# How to concatenate two fields in Solr using DIH?

Tags: xml, solr, concatenation, dih

Right now I am trying to concatenate names and some dates when I am importing XML files using DIH.

I have been trying the solution here: https://bryanbende.com/development/2015/01/31/concatenating-fields-with-apache-solr. But I have gotten nowhere.

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="concatFields">
  <processor class="solr.CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="source">author_fname</str>
    <str name="dest">author_name</str>
  </processor>
  <processor class="solr.CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="source">author_lname</str>
    <str name="dest">author_name</str>
  </processor>
  <processor class="solr.ConcatFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="fieldName">author_name</str>
    <str name="delimiter">_</str>
  </processor>
  <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
  <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
</updateRequestProcessorChain>

<requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="update.chain">concatFields</str>
     </lst>
 </requestHandler>
```

Comment: Hi there.  I see you are new to Stack Overflow so I wanted to say Welcome to the community.  The link you provided points to a thread where several question/reseponse messages exist.  Can you include the last thing that you tried and say what the error was that you received?  This will help someone else reproduce the problem and provide an answer.  Best wishes.

Comment: Sorry I just realized I posted the wrong link https://bryanbende.com/development/2015/01/31/concatenating-fields-with-apache-solr

I didn't receive any errors when I tried that attempt, but I was not able to index the concatenated fields